# How to customize the error message, when unique constraint fails, for dynamically chosen fields in the view?

Tags: django-forms

I have created a form, where users (buyer) can send in offers to other users (seller). I want the buyer to only be able to send one offer to one seller, and not multiple offers. I have then defined a unique constraint for two fields, the buyer, and seller. If the buyer sends a offer, it goes through, and if the buyer sends one more for the same seller, the unique constraint fails.

```py
class Offer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='user')
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='buyer')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    created_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    message = models.TextField(null=True)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'buyer']
```

The problem I have is that I have no idea on how to customize the unique constraint for my form, because the fields are defined in my view.

```py
# app_name: users
"""
I have defined a view that uses FormMixin and DetailView.
The SellerDetailView handles the GET requests, and the OfferFormView handles the POST requests.
I have then combined this in one view, SellerView.
"""
class SellerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Seller 
    context_object_name = 'seller'
    template_name = "core/seller_detail.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = OfferForm()
        return context

class SellerView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = SellerDetailView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = OfferFormView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)


# app_name: payment
class OfferFormView(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "core/seller_detail.html"
    form_class = OfferForm
    model = Seller 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            seller = self.get_object()
            form.instance.user = seller.user 
            form.instance.buyer = self.request.user
            form.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return _(# Not important)
```

I could, define the validation in my view, but I would rather not, and I would rather do the validation in my forms.py instead, like how I validate my other fields.

```py
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class OfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ['price', 'date', 'message'] 
        widgets = {
            'date' : DateInput,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Using FormHelper from crispy-forms, not important.

    def clean_price(self):
        price = self.cleaned_data['price']

        if price < 100:
            raise ValidationError('Tilbud kan ikke være lavere enn 100 Kr.')
        
        return price 
    
    def clean_date(self):
        date = self.cleaned_data['date'] 
        picked_date = datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d').date()

        if picked_date < date.today():
            raise ValidationError('Kan ikke planlegge dato før idag.')

        return date
```

## What I tried:

I have tried using the get_initial() method from FormMixin to define the initial values for user and buyer.

```py
class OfferFormView(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "core/seller_detail.html"
    form_class = OfferForm
    model = Seller 
    # Defined initial values for user and buyer.
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['user'] = self.get_object().user
        initial['buyer'] = self.request.user

        return initial

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        seller = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return _(# Not important)
```

Then I tried validating this with the method clean() from ModelForm.

```py
class OfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ['price', 'date', 'message'] 
        widgets = {
            'date' : DateInput,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # Using FormHelper from crispy-forms, not important.

    def clean(self):
        # data_cleaned = super().clean()
        
        # Values predefined from get_initial() method from FormView
        user = self.initial.get('user') 
        buyer = self.initial.get('buyer')
        
        
        # Expecting an error. If offer exists.
        if Offer.objects.filter(user=user, buyer=buyer).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Du har allerede lagd et tilbud.')

        # Just returns blank values for user and buyer, not initial.
        # return data_cleaned

    def clean_price(self):
        price = self.cleaned_data['price']

        if price < 100:
            raise ValidationError('Tilbud kan ikke være lavere enn 100 Kr.')
        
        return price 
    
    def clean_date(self):
        date = self.cleaned_data['date'] 
        picked_date = datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d').date()

        if picked_date < date.today():
            raise ValidationError('Kan ikke planlegge dato før idag.')

        return date
```

If offer never existed, then it would just create a object with user and buyer as blank. That is because data_cleaned for those fields are blank. I thought maybe the initial values defined values for cleaned_data? If so, then is there a way for me to define the values for cleaned_data in view? Then handle validation for them in clean() method from ModelForm?

Answer (score 0):

## Forget everything I said above...

I added the method `validate_unique()` [`Model.validate_unique()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) for my model.

It makes sense that I should handle the validation, that are unique to the model itself, and not the forms.py...

```py
class Offer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='user')
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='buyer')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    created_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    message = models.TextField(null=True)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'buyer']

    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        super().validate_unique(exclude=exclude) 

        if Offer.objects.filter(user=self.user, buyer=self.buyer).exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                _('Error...')
            )
```

Problem is that the values in this, self.user and self.buyer are both None. Any idea how to use the values from the view, here?

Forget it, I'm stupid, I fixed it.

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
        
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        # Moved these three out of the form.is_valid() 
        """
        if the form is valid, it has ran all the validations. 
        I should define these values before validating.
        """
        seller = self.get_object()
        form.instance.user = seller.user 
        form.instance.buyer = self.request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super().form_invalid(form)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return _(# not important)
```